# when I hit yarn run dev . it shows 'next' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've installed `yarn create next-app my-app`. Then when I tried to run this command `yarn dev` It shows the error `next is not recognized as an internal or external command`, operable program or batch file.

Please provide the solution. I've already spent the whole day to fix this :(

Comment: Have you installed `next` globally on your machine? If so, I would recommend not to.

Comment: ️ check alt solution  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68473031/8621764

Comment: If you're using Yarn PnP (i.e. no node_modules folder) ensure that the .yarnrc.yml file contains `nodeLinker: "pnp"`. This was the source of the error for me.

Answer (score 40):

this is because your system does not have the "next npm"

**follow to fix:**

1. visit your project dir
2. open terminal
3. **hit the command** `npm install next`

Answer (score 14):

Follow steps for solution :

this is solution for all OS like windows ,ubuntu

1. Open Terminal / command prompt
2. Install next in your system with this command

> npm install next -g

Now close terminal and open it again **next --help**. You can see now your able to use next command in your whole system

Comment: this is only helped me. Because the project was cloned. Thank you. If you cloned the project,  try this.

Comment: The -g part installs it globally and is bad practice.

Answer (score 8):

Try following steps:

```
npx create-next-app project-name
cd project-name
npm run dev

# or

yarn create next-app project-name
cd project-name
yarn dev
```

---

*If you are still facing the same issue then try **Manual Setup**:*

```
npm install next react react-dom
# or
yarn add next react react-dom
```

Then, open `package.json` and add the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "next start"
}
```

For more info or help, please visit: [NextJS Getting Started](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score 6):

Do Manually Setup. It will work for you.
If you are in Visual Studio Code then follow this step:

1. Go to Terminal > New Terminal
2. cd `Your file name` (for example my-project is my file name than `cd my-project`)
3. Next Copy the following command

> ```
> npm install next react react-dom
> OR
> yarn add next react react-dom
> ```

Answer (score 2):

same error.
I corrected by running `npm install next react react-dom` than add `import React from 'react'` in _app.js

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. Even though my package.json had "next" as below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "latest", // like this
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
},
```

But running `yarn run dev` or `yarn dev` gave the same error that next is not recognized...

I fixed it by running `yarn add next` which made my package.json dependencies as:

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "^11.1.2", // this changed
    "next-auth": "^3.29.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
```

Then on `yarn run dev` the error didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Install next for that. Use the below command :

```
npm install next
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this with adding absolute path to the script with current project's next command file

```
"devwin": "./node_modules/.bin/next.cmd dev -p 3005"
```

[image: path for window]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late for this debate, but it can be solved deleting .next folder from your project and rebuilding it with yarn dev.

Hope it work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow these easy steps:

Open terminal (press ctrl + J)
Press (ctrl + C

**run these commands**

rm -rf node_modules

yarn cache clean

npm install next

**These Dependencies will be install automatically**

Installing devDependencies (yarn):

- @types/react
- @types/node

after that
run these commands

npm install next react react-dom

or

yarn add next react react-dom

or

pnpm add next react react-dom

**Booooom!**

its done.

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution I have used all the solution like re-installing the package, modified the package.json ex... none of those worked for me.
but for me I've just updated Node.js version and it's worked for me. Use below steps to update your node.js version from cmd only.

- (If you have already nvm installed then skip this step)
  https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases go here and download
  nvm-setup.zip or nvm-setup.exe.
- Unzip it and install it.
- Now open your cmd and type nvm install 
  **Ex. nvm install 20.10.0**
- After installation type nvm use 
  **Ex. nvm use 20.10.0**
- Now you will be able to run your next.js project.

Answer (score 0):

1-Clear npm cache:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

2-Update npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

### If you use npm

```
npm install
npm install react react-dom next

npm run dev
```

### If you use yarn

```
yarn install
yarn add react react-dom next

yarn dev
```